# What is one word for a person who is emotionally bipolar and can't hide his emotions at all?

Tags: emotions, polysemes

He is sad, he bursts into tears and when happy his heart knows no bounds. He is that transparent person when it comes to emotions. An open book!! I am looking for a word for it, if it exists.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like **mercurial** for this purpose. [Link.](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/mercurial)

> subject to sudden or unpredictable changes of mood or mind: his
>   mercurial temperament

Comment: Thanks @eric but if the word could highlight the transparency in showing those sudden emotions as well.

Answer (score 2):

Consider, **volatile**.

> (of a person) liable to display rapid changes of emotion. [OED](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/volatile)

Answer (score 0):

Labile would be the appropriate psychiatric term. Otherwise, are we talking somebody diagnosed as bipolar (mood swings on the order of months to years)? In that case you can use the colloquial "manic-depressive." Using mental health "diagnoses" outside of actual psychology as part of an expression is offensive to the mentally ill and their providers. As such, I downgraded your question. Disinhibited is also appropriate (without the hyphen).

Answer (score -1):

Someone who suddenly bursts into tears when they are only sad, or appears to be greatly animated when they feel happiness or excited about anything can be described as
**acting manic**: *[showing wild and apparently deranged excitement and energy](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/manic).*

A more sensitive expression without the negative connotations is ***effusive***

> Showing or expressing gratitude, pleasure, or approval in an unrestrained or heartfelt manner *[‘an effusive welcome’](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/effusive)*

<sub>Oxford Dictionaries</sub>

Answer (score -1):

I guess it's impossible to find out a better word than : bipolar
http://www.nimh.nih.gov/health/topics/bipolar-disorder/index.shtml

Comment: Baiwir's comment is insulting. I'm sorry if you don't understand why.

Comment: Sorry, not understood. Please tell me why.

Comment: The term BIPOLAR is a psychiatric diagnosis. To use it in any other fashion is insulting to the mental health community. Others include calling the weather SCHIZOPHRENIC for frequently changing patterns or looking with an AUTISTIC expression. DEPRESSED can be used adjectively, though, but that's based on Webster's: "We lived through a depressed economy." It's the equivalent of ... I'm not going to finish that thought. Try labile or liability--it works.

Comment: It is not necessary to consider the bipolar term under the pscychiatric angle, there are several degrees between what is admitted as being the standard and what is considered as by moving away too much.

Comment: I have no idea what you're talking about. It's insulting; you shouldn't do it; I don't think it's more complicated than that. Of course there are a few examples where using a highly insulting term would be acceptable in fiction ...